# Array to map based on object property containing array items

Tags: javascript, node.js

If i have a object like following

```
result  = [
 {
   phones : ["ABC", "DEF"],
   name: "Simon"
 },
 {
   phones : ["ABC", "XZY"],
   name: "John"
 }
]
```

Expected output

Map of key, value

```
{ABC,     ["Simon", "John"]}
{DEF,     ["Simon"]}
{XYZ,     ["John"]}
```

My try

```
map: Map = new Map();   
for ( r of result ) {
   for( phone of r.phones) {
      if(map.get(phone)){
        map.set(phone, map.get(phone).concat(r.name))
      } else {
        map.set(phone, r.name);
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a ES6 way to perform the above double iteration in a minimised way ?

Answer (score 3):

**Overall** Your code is quite reasonable, after fixing something that looks to be a typo. The transformation that needs to be applied to the data structure isn't entirely trivial, so the logic that needs to be implemented requires a handful of lines of code.

**Typo?** But your code also has a typo/bug: the `map.set(phone, r.name);` will set the value in the map to be a *string*, not an array. You probably meant to do `map.set(phone, [r.name]);` (maybe a miscopy?) There's also `map: Map = new Map();`, which isn't valid syntax in JS, remove the `: Map` part.

**Conditional operator** If you wanted to shorten your existing code, see how you're using `.map.set(phone, someExpression)` depending on a condition - this is a sign that you can use the conditional operator instead of the `if`/`else`.

```
map.set(phone, (map.get(phone) ?? []).concat(r.name));
```

But while that makes the code *shorter*, is it easier to read? I'm not entirely convinced. Maybe you'll like it, or maybe you won't.

There are a few other things that can improve the code quality:

**Declare your variables** Doing `for (r of result)` will implicitly create a global `r` variable and put it on the global object. If you're running in strict mode, this will throw an error too. Always declare variables before using them, preferably with `const`.

**Destructure?** With `for (r of result)` or `for (const r of result)`, you create a variable named `r`, which isn't so intuitive - what's an `r`? Maybe destructure the `name` and `phones` properties immediately.

```js
const result  = [
 {
   phones : ["ABC", "DEF"],
   name: "Simon"
 },
 {
   phones : ["ABC", "XZY"],
   name: "John"
 }
]
const map = new Map();
for (const { phones, name } of result) {
  for (const phone of phones) {
    map.set(phone, (map.get(phone) ?? []).concat(name));
  }
}
console.log([...map]);
```